# How to enter datetime variables from keyboard in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, input, keyboard

I need to enter from my keyboard data according to date / month / year format.

I try code like this :

```
   DateTime dt = new DateTime();
   dt = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

But when input date I still enter year first. So how can I fix this. Thanks!

Comment: either parse the input splitting on `/` to separate the elements or use 3 prompts.

Comment: What exactly you are entering as input.

Comment: may be something like this `DateTime dt = new DateTime(); 
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Program error at: dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at a dotnetfiddle of my solution [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/juvl5L).

If you look at the DateTime constructor [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_), you'll see that the constructor takes in `int year, int month, int day` in that order, which doesn't match OP's target format. Take a look at my answer for an easy solution.

You can also find the code below:

```
string targetDateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
DateTime dt;

Console.WriteLine("Enter a date in the format day/month/year");
string enteredDateString = Console.ReadLine();

//This is assuming the string entered is of the correct format, I suggest doing some validation
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(enteredDateString, targetDateFormat,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

//This will print in month/day/year format
Console.WriteLine(dt);

//This will print in day/month/year format
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

**You'll need to add the following using declarations to your code:**

`using System.Globalization;`

Comment: Program error at: dt = DateTime.ParseExact(enteredDateString, targetDateFormat,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: add ```using System.Globalization;``` to the top of your code

Comment: The input date format you expect is day/month/year, right?
This code works, as you can see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/juvl5L) when you hit run and enter a date in the format you stated above. 
I suggest copying the code from the link I posted and replacing your code with it to see what happens. You can also edit your post and post all of your code so I can help further.

Comment: Oh it works!!! Thank you so much!!! I realise there is big difference when I enter day is 8 and day is 08!!! This make program error

Answer (score 2):

Can you show me your Main method in Program.cs? I'm wondering if maybe marking the readline with a verbatim string literal might help. Also you should probably use TryParse so you can handle.

```
if (!DateTime.TryParse($@"{Console.ReadLine()}", out DateTime result))
{
    throw new FormatException("The Date you entered is not a valid date");
}

Console.WriteLine($"{result.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")}");
```

Comment: Take a look at the DateTime constructor [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_).

The constructor takes in ```int year, int month, int day``` in that order, which doesn't match OP's target format. Take a look at my answer for an easy solution

Comment: We're not using the constructor ourselves here. I've tried this code in RoslynPad and it parses 12/14/2016 and 2016/12/14 the exact same.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have googled the docs for tryparse before I commented. Nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget date formats are different around the world.   UK uses day/month/year, US uses month/day/year and China use year/month/day.  Beyond that, the separator can also be different (some use slash, some cultures use dash etc).

`DateTime.Parse` will use the culture that was detected at startup from the O/S.   If you want to override this, then you should use `DateTime.ParseExact` (where you specify the exact pattern), or pass `DateTime.Parse` the culture you wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

To begin, you have to import

```
using System.Globalization;
```

in the header of your code for it to work, after you just put this code

```
DateTime dt;
dt = DateTime.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
Console.WriteLine (dt.ToString ("d"
    CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture ("NZ-in")));
Console.ReadLine ();
```

For more information, visit this web page

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings
```